# Which class to import to declare a toolbar variable unsing androidx

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androidx

I am trying to build a toolbar. When I declare the toolbar variable in my Java main activity, I expect to reference Toolbar object.

I put the error in comments, I think it has to do with the androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

----here is my main activity xml file ----

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="TAB1" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="TAB2" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="TAB3" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="TAB4" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="TAB5" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    >

</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:context=".TvatActivity">

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

-----here is my mainactivity.java file

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.

class TvatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private Toolbar toolbar; //Expecting Member declaration    
    private TableLayout tableLayout;  //Expecting Member declaration  
    private ViewPager viewpager; //Expecting Member declaration    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar); //unresolved reference toolbar 
        tabLayout =(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs); //unresolved reference tabLayout
        viewpager =(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);  //unresolved reference  viewpager

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setSupportViewPager(viewpager);
        tableLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
    }
```

----QND HERE IS MY AAP gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.youthimpact.tvap"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.4.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Comment: In general, you have to check your layout files, and assign ids to views there. Then you have to understand the root view or activity to call findViewById on it.

Comment: Well structured questions get more attention on Stack-overflow. I suggest you provide more information to support your question. For example you could include you build.gradle to show what dependencies and api versions you are using and the xml for activity_main. More help here here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sure i agree with you ; i have attached the xml , .java , the app gradle

Answer (score 0):

Normally in your xml Layout with Androidx you have

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And set NoActionBar theme in your Manifest

Comment: yes i did both , i had set NoActionBar in the manifest and com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout for the layout

Comment: i hava added more information to my post , the .xml file , .java and the gradle app